# How to add custom css in swagger-ui using .Net

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

Hi I'm using swagger ui in my web api project. It's very good but i am facing some ui issue in page.

this is the snapshot
[image: swagger ui issue in right side of json]

How can I fix this issue by adding custom css. if i have to add custom css then where i have to add. in project file or in swagger ui project then i have to import. I am also using swashbuckle to show respone message.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Related: [Modifications to Swagger UI header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36291146/113116), [Swagger (Swashbuckle) hide header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31636969/113116), [How to replace Swagger UI header logo in Swashbuckle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38713764/113116), [Replace Swashbuckle UI completely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31647635/113116), [Swagger UI themes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28033075/113116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifications to Swagger UI header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291146/modifications-to-swagger-ui-header)

Answer (score 1):

In swashbuckle there is an option:
`InjectStylesheet`
that should do exactly what you need.
That is located in the `SwaggerConfig.cs` and is relatively simple to integrate.

See my example here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L238

Comment: I have injected my css and i am overwriting this class.   .swagger-section .swagger-ui-wrap .model-signature pre  or code{
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
} but it's not working on very big json file.

Comment: @Jitendrasingh Can you be more specific? Can you see the CSS you injected?

Comment: @Jitendrasingh Maybe you can create a minimal project on GitHub showing your issue?

Comment: in normal project i am not getting this issue, could you please suggest how can we fix by writing custom css in that fiel.

Comment: Your question is about: How to add custom css in swagger-ui using .Net... is that part working now?

Comment: this is the project url i have created today.        https://github.com/jitsingh89/JIT.Swagger.git

Comment: @Jitendrasingh If that is working fine then question has been answered. you have now a different problem.

Comment: In Your sample project you have not enabled the `InjectStylesheet` option

Comment: @Jitendrasingh I sent you a Pull Request on GitHub, your project had MANY many issues!

Comment: Thanks HelderSepu